# Lenovo docking station won't turn on monitors on boot

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, thunderbolt, docking

I have a Lenovo X1 Extreme and Lenovo Thunderbolt docking station 40AN0230EU

https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x/ThinkPad-X1-Extreme/p/22TP2TXX1E1

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500252

**When laptop is connected to the docking station it won't turn on the extra monitors on boot (which are connected directly to docking station).**

I first need to open the laptop lid and log in and only then the extra monitors turn on.

This is a more technical question, but I hope someone could come to an idea what can I try to do so that the monitors turn on when the laptop boots to the login screen.

---

Update: This seems only a problem under Ubuntu, windows users don't have any problems with this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the thunderbolt was authorized properly (if not, try doing so, for example http://juho.tykkala.fi/Lenovo-Thunderbolt-3-dock-Linux ) and your problem is that the monitor is not "recognized" on start up. Have you tried to change the monitor's settings from "auto" to the port hdmi/dp where the monitor is connected?

Another thing is how the nvidia driver is setup, for example - load the the kernel modules as early as possible: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1068925/linux/prime-render-offloading-not-working-on-my-arch-linux-on-a-lenovo-laptop-with-xfce-xorg/ ( search for `MODULES=` ).

Two years ago I had similar problem and back then the workaround I came with was (instructions are for Arch Linux, but it should be something similar):

Create monitor configuration for both internal (lcd panel) and external (monitor):

```
$ sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DP1"
    Option      "Primary" "true"
    Option  "PreferredMode" "3840x2160_60.00"
    Option  "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "eDP1"
    Option      "LeftOf" "DP1"
    Option  "DPMS" "true"
EndSection
```

Create an executable file, so `xinit` run it on startup:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/90-display.sh

#!/bin/sh   
xrandr --output "eDP1" --off --output "DP1" --primary --auto
xrandr --output "eDP-1-1" --off --output "DP-1-1" --primary --auto
```

This will turn off the LCD panel. You can add explicit xrandr command to turn your external monitor "DP1" --on.

Let me know if you managed to solve your problem. Soon, I'll probably go though the same problem (X1 + 40AN0230EU + 4k monitor)

Comment: Currently I'm on vacation... when i get back home I will try this and make an update

Comment: So i don't actually have Ubuntu... I'm on PopOS and there is no such file: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf` :(

Comment: Do you have /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ directory? You are supposed to create a new file 10-monitor.conf inside.

P.S. I have already X1+40AN0230EU, but still have absolutely no time to install anything and still sits with windows home...

Comment: I reinstalled the PopOs with newer version (19.10) and now everything  works

Comment: Update: I'm now back on Ubuntu 20.04 because again I had problems with docking station on popos 20.04

Comment: I bought a Dell U2720Q and I totally retired the docking station. The monitor supports USB-C charging (100W), as well video forwarding through USB-C, so almost no reason to use a separate docking and works great on Manjaro/Arch.

Comment: But you have only one ext. monitor i suppose?

Comment: @lewis4u yes, I'm using single external monitor. This particular monitor U2720Q, does not support DP forwarding, but I guess such monitors exist that support DP chaining through USB-C.
I'm just sick of those docking stations. Moreover, since I'm doing homework for awhile, I use the same monitor to switch between my home laptop (lenovo) and mac used for work, by using the same monitor, mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Yeah. There is no need for docking station when using just one monitor